# Serialize datatable with bindingsource to Json

Tags: json, vb.net, winforms, json.net

I have a REST API from which I get the JSON data back.
The JSON model looks like the following:

```json
{  
  "Id": "",
  "Name": "",
  "ExternalId": "",
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Name": "",
      "DisplayAt": ""
    }
  ],
  "Rows": [
    "Array[string]"
  ],
  "NewRows": [
    "Array[string]"
  ],
  "DeletedRows": [
    "Array[string]"
  ],
  "CompanyId": 0,
  "IntegrationKey": ""
}
```

I've made a Class model that looks like the following:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Namespace Models
    Public Class Header
        <JsonProperty("Name")>
        Public Property Name As String

        <JsonProperty("DisplayAt")>
        Public Property DisplayAt As String
    End Class

    Public Class DataSource
        <JsonProperty("Id")>
        Public Property Id As String

        <JsonProperty("Name")>
        Public Property Name As String

        <JsonProperty("Headers")>
        Public Property Headers As Header()

        <JsonProperty("Rows")>
        Public Property Rows As String()()

        <JsonProperty("TotalRows")>
        Public Property TotalRows As Integer

        <JsonProperty("LastUpdated")>
        Public Property LastUpdated As DateTime

        <JsonProperty("CompanyId")>
        Public Property CompanyId As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Category
        <JsonProperty("DataSource")>
        Public Property DataSource As DataSource
    End Class
End Namespace
```

From the array rows I retrieve all my necessary data which is saved in a datatable. Via a BindingSource all the fields are bound to the listbox and all changes are saved to the datatable.
The JSON is deserialized with NewtonSoft.

Now I want to save the changes back to the database via a PUT statement. Therefore I have to serialize the datatable.
I can do that with the following code:

```
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(datatable, Formatting.Indented)
```

In this case I'm getting only the array from the Rows in a nice JSON format.

My first question is:
How do I serialize the datatable so that I can also pass the ID and externalID in my JSON?

My second question:
Does it updates all the datarows from the database or is it also possible to just update the  changed rows?

Comment: Whats the format of the PUT request? The datatable serialized probably won't be the correct format.

Comment: @CoolCoder123. The PUT request is the same format as the GET request. If I serialize the datatable the format will be incorrect for the PUT request. If I can insert the serialized datatable into the Rows array the format would be perfect.

Comment: Why dont you create an instance of your class based on the datatable.

Comment: Can you give an example. I don’t understand what you mean.

Comment: Your model does not match the JSON you give. You can use this site to convert JSON to vb classes https://json2any.com/